# Best way to parse complex JSON

Tags: java, json

I am trying to find the best solution for parsing my JSON to Map.
I am planning to use Jackson and Bind it with the complex objects and do some iteration to create a flat map out of it.
Please let me know if any simple way which is supportive for extension in future

Input JSON :

```
Data={
  "Name": "IT dept",
  "DeptProducts": [
    {
      "RepresentorsName": "BOB",
      "Product": "SOFTWARE",
      "Account": "123456",
      "AccountType": "Saving"
    },
    {
      "RepresentorsName": "BOB",
      "Product": "HARDWARE",
      "Account": "1234567",
      "AccountType": "Saving"
    }
  ],
  "DeptClients": [
    {
      "ClientName": "GOOGLE",
      "ClientRegion": "US",
      "ClientCode": "1111"
    }
  ],
  "Faculty": [
    {
      "Name": "Tom",
      "Email": null,
      "FacultyProducts": [
        {
          "RepresentorsName": "BOB",
          "Product": "SOFTWARE",
          "Account": "123456",
          "AccountType": "Saving"
        },
        {
          "RepresentorsName": "BOB",
          "Product": "HARDWARE",
          "Account": "1234567",
          "AccountType": "Saving"
        }
      ],
      "Righs": [
        {
          "Product": "SOFTWARE",
          "Type": "Local",
          "Righs": "ENABLED"
        },
        {
          "Product": "SOFTWARE",
          "Type": "Online",
          "Righs": "ENABLED"
        },
         {
          "Product": "HARDWARE",
          "Type": "Local",
          "Righs": "ENABLED"
        }

      ],
      "Clients": [
        {
          "ClientName": "GOOGLE",
          "Region": "US",
          "AccountType": 2,
          "AccountNumber": "123456",
          ],
          "Representors": [
            {
              "RepresentorsName": "BOB",
              "Country": "United States"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "Representors": [
        {
          "RepresentorsName": "BOB",
          "Country": "United States"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Representors": [
    {
      "RepresentorsName": "BOB",
      "Country": "United States"
    }
  ]
}
```

So the hierarchy is  like :

```
Department      
    -DeptProducts:Array 
    -DeptClients:Array  
    -Faculty:Array  
        -FacultyProducts:Array
        -Righs:Array
        -Clients:Array
        -Representor:Array
    -Representor:Array
```

So I should be able to create a map that has key = Name+Product+Type for each faculty.
Also each faculty is replicated against each group matching with and the result is again replicated by type by matching products.
So from above JSON, I want the following Map (I represented as a table for a simplified view and not filled all the information).
Also if other informations at faculty level is missing then it should fill it from Dept level as same information present at Dept level also (We need to match faculty level info with dept and then fetch other info accordingly)

```
+------+-----------------+--------+-------+--------+----+
| Name | FacultyProducts |  Type  | info1 | info2  | …. |
+------+-----------------+--------+-------+--------+----+
| Tom  | SOFTWARE        | Local  |       |        |    |
| Tom  | HARDWARE        | Online |       |        |    |
| Tom  | HARDWARE        | Local  |       |        |    |
+------+-----------------+--------+-------+--------+----+
```

Comment: You can convert json to java object and use some java 8 Streams (map, filter, groupingBy, etc.) to convert to the target format.

Comment: @Smile What is preferable, json-> java object or json -> Map<String,Obj> ?